# Twitter Bootstrap tab shown event not firing on page load

Tags: javascript, events, tabs, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

In a page where I have *n* tabs, and the following script (coffeescript, I checked the compiled javascript and it seems to be ok)...

```
$ ->
    init()

init = ->
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on 'shown', (event) ->
        shown = event.target
        console.log("Showing tab: " + shown)
```

Now, the 'shown' event does not fire on page load, so for the first tab being shown on the page there's no way to handle this (ie: loading content via xhr)

I tried adding this to the above script, to see if triggering it manually could work:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]:first').tab 'show'
```

... but it didn't.

This is the HTML code I use in my view

```
<div class="tabbable">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#updates" data-toggle="tab"><%=t :updates, :scope => 'user.profile.sections'%></a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="#activity" data-toggle="tab"><%=t :activity, :scope => 'user.profile.sections'%></a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="#articles" data-toggle="tab"><%=t :articles, :scope => 'user.profile.sections'%></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="updates">

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="activity">

    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="articles">

    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try leaving the class `active` off both the tab `<li>` and the content `<div>`.  One of the first [lines of code in the `show()` method](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-tab.js#L50) is to short-circuit if the tab being requested is already active.

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FStGU/)

Comment: Give merv the answer, this is the solution

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. Leaving off the active class made my tab look not selected. Simply triggering the event in JS did work though.

Comment: As Bpainter says, this doesn't appear to work anymore. Leaving off `class='active'` simply leaves the tab looking unselected. Using an `onload` event with Diego's code would seem to be the only solution at present.

Answer (score 13):

You can trigger the event manually when you tell the page to show the tab:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]:first').trigger("shown.bs.tab");
```

Comment: $('a[data-toggle="tab"]:first').tab('show') is perhaps a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing Bootstrap Javascript Toggable tabs and Basic tabs managed by classes and id's

In case you want to use Javascript to manage the tabs you should delete the data-toggle="tab" from the anchors on the LI elements as shown here: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tabs

You can compare the syntax with basics tabs: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navs

Answer (score 0):

After my

```
$("#modal").modal('show');
```

I added this and it worked just fine:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]:first').click();
```