# Bootstrap 3 Default to first tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dynamic modal with two tabs. I want `#tab1` to always be the default tab when someone opens the modal. The problem is if I open the modal and click on `#tab2` then close, when I open the modal it is still on `#tab2`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9zo9hka4/

I'm not sure how do it. I've tried setting the tab back to `#tab1` when I see the `.on('hidden.bs.modal'` event but that doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) you can activate the first tab like this:

```
$('#myTab a:first').tab('show')
```

So just add that to your modal when it's closed like this:

```
$('#clusterprofileanomalies').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    //Add this line:
    $('.nav-tabs a:first').tab('show');

    //Snipped other non-relevant code
});
```

Update of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sesu6rkn/1/

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this before and if I recall I had to remove the class="active" from both tab and tabContent.

This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11762931/1214858

Answer (score 1):

i used this works fine i guess

```
$('.nav-tabs > li:first-child > a')[0].click();
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, so I found this as solution for the problem. I just trigger a click event on the first link:

```
$('.nav-tabs a:first').click();
```